# Hibernate - 'class not found while looking for property' when used join

Tags: hibernate

I am using the `<join>` in my entity mapping and Hibernate keeps throwing the error class TechnologyCatalogSummary not found while looking for property: version

---

Hibernate Mapping

```
<class entity-name="Summary" table="CATALOG" mutable="true" name="Catalog">
    <id name="CatId" column="cat_id"/>
    <property name="Name" column="Cat_Name" />
    <property name="version" column="version" />
    <property name="edition" column="edition" length="255" />
    <property name="platform" column="platform" length="50" />

    <join table="v_techClsfnLvl">  
        <key column="cat_id"/>  
        <property name="level" column="Level"/>
    </join>

</class>
```

---

Exception:
*Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: class Summary not found while looking for property: level*

But, my class Catalog actually have the property 'level' and I don't understand why the exception says class not found on the entity name ('Summary')

Appreciate your time!

Comment: Where is Catalog.java located? Give us the package of this class

Comment: Catalog.java is in com.domaindto.catalog
same as the <hibernate-mapping package="com.domaindto.catalog">

Comment: just did a quick test by taking out the <join> and using the <property name="level" column="Level"/>
Now it doesn't complain on the property but instead complains on the column, which makes perfect sense as this column is on a different table (v_techClsfnLvl, which I am trying to join)

Comment: another finding, it doesn't complain if i remove the entity-name on the class def. Not sure why the entity-name would cause this behavior, is this a bug in Hibernate?